# INT to decimal JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for method to achieve the following:

```
var exampleIntOne = 170;
var exampleIntTwo = 1700;
var exampleIntThree = 17000;
var exampleIntFour = 170000;
```

I would like to be able to convert the above to the following expected result:

```
1.70
17.00
170.00
1700.00
```

I have tried: `exampleIntOne.toFixed(2);` but this turns that example into: `170.00`

Comment: So... divide it by `100`...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just  /100 wont give desired result. Have to do .toFixed(2) too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: Could you please respond to the answer so that i / (we) can know it is working for you or if you need any changes let know.

Comment: @BernardY can you please comment if it worked for you? And if yes, i would request you to mark it green.

Comment: @AKA testing now, will mark as green if all looks good thanks!

Comment: Ok @BernardV i will be waiting for you.

Comment: @AKA thanks, works fine; also I think I should have thought just 20 seconds more on this problem before asking the question bit of a silly question to ask... :)

Comment: I can understand. The Javascript is by default silly. We have to think clever to make it through @BernardV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```js
function parseDecimal(numberVal){
   return (numberVal / 100).toFixed(2);
}

var exampleIntOne = 170 
console.log(parseDecimal(exampleIntOne));
var exampleIntTwo = 1700
console.log(parseDecimal(exampleIntTwo));
var exampleIntThree = 17000
console.log(parseDecimal(exampleIntThree));
var exampleIntFour = 170000
console.log(parseDecimal(exampleIntFour));
```

Where `parseDecimal()` is your common method to get the desired output format.

Comment: I don't think you need parseFloat here.

Answer (score 3):

```
(yourNumber/100).toFixed(2)
```

[That should do](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/8n5a3ed6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function convertNum(num){
   var numStr=num.toString();   
   numStr=numStr.slice(0,-2);
   var newValue=numStr+'.'+'00';  
   return newValue;  
}
console.log(convertNum(17000));
```